# ElasticSearch source filtering array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Here is a document

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Name": "Thing",
  "Prices": [
    {"CompanyId": "1", "Price": "11.11"},
    {"CompanyId": "2", "Price": "12.12"},
    {"CompanyId": "3", "Price": "13.13"}
```

And here is the associated ElasticSearch schema:

```
"Prices" : {
    "type" : "nested",
    "properties" : {
        "CompanyId": {
            "type" : "integer"
        },
        "Price" : {
            "type" : "scaled_float",
            "scaling_factor" : 100
        }
    }
}
```

If a user is buying for `CompantId = 3` then the supplier doesn't want them to be able to see the preferential pricing for `CompanyId = 1`, say.

Therefore I need to use a source filter to remove all prices for which the `CompanyId` is not `3`.

I have found that this works.

```
"_source":{
  "excludes": ["Prices.companyId.CompanyId"]
}
```

But I don't understand how or why.
It can't possibly work because the required `CompanyId` is not mentioned anywhere in the whole ElasticSearch search JSON.

Adding a full search JSON:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match_all":{

               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":{
            "match":{
               "PurchasingViews":6060
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size":20,
   "aggs":{
      "CompanyName.raw":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"CompanyName.raw",
            "size":20,
            "order":{
               "_count":"desc"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "_source":{
      "excludes":[
         "PurchasingViews",
         "ContractFilters",
         "SearchField*",
         "Keywords*",
         "Menus*",
         "Prices.companyId.CompanyId"
      ]
   }
}
```

Result:

```
{
   "took":224,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":1173525,
      "max_score":1.0,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"products_purchasing",
            "_type":"product_purchasing",
            "_id":"12787114",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{
               "CompanyName":"...",
               "Prices":[
                  {
                     "CompanyId":1474,
                     "Price":697.3
                  }
               ],
               "CompanyId":571057,
               "PartNumber":"...",
               "LongDescription_en":"...",
               "Name_en":"...",
               "DescriptionSnippet_en":"...",
               "ProductId":9605985,
               "Id":12787114
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations":{
      "CompanyName.raw":{
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound":84,
         "sum_other_doc_count":21078,
         "buckets":[
            {
               "key":"...",
               "doc_count":534039
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the query you're sending and the result you're seeing?

Comment: Can you add all that to your question instead, as it's more legible, thx

Comment: Just worked out that by coincidence the filter reduces the results to documents that only have one price.

So the question remains: how do I write a source filter to remove all prices for which the CompanyId is not 3.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

I believe the way you have put your mapping with the "nested" type has created the reference you are questioning.

Also - I would suggest framing the query as looking for 3 only rather than "excluding" everything except 3